# Can we switch desktop ( GNOME, KDE, etc ) within linux?

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, kde, desktop-environment

I started using linux mint 13 mate yesterday. Although the words from their site is promising, I found it lack some ways for configuration.

For example, I want to enlarge the scroll bar so that I can easily locate it ( I am using a trackball which doesn't come with a scroll wheel, so I need to drag the scroll bar in windows ). After looking up all the option in Control Center, I failed to found a solution.

Can we switch to another desktop such as KDE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can, for example you can run following command for installing KDE desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-standard
```

Or for full set of package/applications (it may take a lot of tim) you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

after next login select KDE from "session" on the Login Prompt to start enjoying the Kool Desktop Environment (KDE).

I recommend if you want to try new desktop, install a fresh one of an specific derivative (e.g. Kubuntu or Mint KDE).

Comment: For the last sentence, Why?

Comment: Because sometimes occur some configuration conflict (for example in display manager, autostart script and ...) between desktop environments and then its functionality do not work complete.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

If you install the new *desktop environment* ([KDE](http://www.kde.org/), [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/), [LXDE](http://lxde.org/), [XFCE](http://xfce.org/), [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments)) you should see a option appear on the login splash-screen. On mint you select *session*, and then select your preferred environment.

This will now be your default environment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure if this is how it normally works, but when I ran

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

on Linux Mint 14 MATE, it asked whether I wanted MATE or KDE as my default.

Answer (score -1):

what about GNOME? I found this page https://itsfoss.com/install-gnome-linux-mint/ . You can use `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop` for minimal installation, or `sudo apt install gnome` for a full install.

And for XFCE, I found this page https://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/ . You can use `sudo apt-get install xfce4` for standard minimal install.